# adding a line break to li:before pseudo-element

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if its possible to add line breaks to a `li:before` pseudo-element so that three words can be displayed one over another
for example something like this:

```
li:before{
content:'hello <br> how<br> are<br>';
}
```

Here is my real code. Its a circle with some text inside it

```
#test li:before{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:5.0rem;
    height:5.0rem;
    background-color:rgb(255,104,0);
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    border-radius:50%;
}
 #landing-page-nav li:after{
        content:"Specials"; 
    /*here i want to add 1 over over the other like this:
    Special
    Offer
    for*/

}
```

I now that doesnt work but its only for the purpose of explaning

thanks for the help

Comment: And, did you try it out? What is the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **\A**

replace `<br>` **To** `\A`

**Css**

```
li:before{
content:'hello \A how \A are \A';
white-space: pre;
}
```

**Snippet Example**

```css
li:before{
content:'hello \A how \A are \A';
white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

**Inside Text In Circle**

```css
ul
{
  list-style-type:none;
}
li:before{
content:'hello \A how \A are \A';
white-space: pre;
}

#test li:before{
    content:'hello \A how \A are \A';
    display:block;
    width:5.0rem;
    height:5.0rem;
    background-color:rgb(255,104,0);
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    border-radius:50%;
    text-align: center;
}
 #landing-page-nav li:after{
        content:"Specials \A Offer \A for"; 
        white-space: pre;
    /*here i want to add 1 over over the other like this:
    Special
    Offer
    for*/

}
```

```html
<ul id="test">
<li></li>
</ul>
<br>
 <ul id="landing-page-nav">
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes, but this is not work for  #landing-page-nav li:after{}  element

Comment: updated my answer..check again.. \a working fine in li::after {}